# Apache log analyzer which outputs user flows

Tags: apache, logging

I'm looking for a peice of software which can help me debug issues on a website by using apache logs. Here's the scenario.

I have a client on a website who has just performed something which is unexpected, I have his IP address because it got logged with a purchased transaction.

Is there a program out there that'll let me view step by step which a selected user did on the site, using the apache logs.

e.g. IP address a.b.c.d set...

```
IP address a.b.c.d
Time Date / Path
18:02     / index.htm
18:03     / shop.htm
18:04     / product1.htm
```

That way I can see exactly how a user arrived where they did.

Thanks for any help you can give.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's one line of bash. I hope you've got your apache log type set to "Combined", and a bash shell at your disposal. Then the command

```
grep $IP $LOGFILE | awk '{ print $4$5, $7, "("$11")" }'
```

will yield something like this (Referers are in parentheses):

```
[07/Mar/2010:14:11:45+0100] /Doku/strawberrylimes.html ("-")
[07/Mar/2010:14:11:45+0100] /doku.css ("http://da.andaka.org/Doku/strawberrylimes.html")
[07/Mar/2010:14:11:45+0100] /images/zutaten.jpg ("http://da.andaka.org/Doku/strawberrylimes.html")
[07/Mar/2010:14:11:56+0100] /images/prost.jpg ("http://da.andaka.org/Doku/strawberrylimes.html")
[07/Mar/2010:14:11:56+0100] /images/vollermixer.jpg ("http://da.andaka.org/Doku/strawberrylimes.html")
[07/Mar/2010:14:11:57+0100] /favicon.ico ("-")
```

(Just remember to replace `$IP` and `$LOGFILE` with your values ... the results are from my webserver and were produced by one page visit.)

If you're only interested in, say, requests for .html files, extend the command line with another grep:

```
grep $IP $LOGFILE | awk '{ print $4$5, $7, "("$11")" }' | grep -E '.+ .+\.html.* .+'
```

The last grep filters out any lines that do *not* have a ".html" string in the second column of the output. But it also filters out all requests on directories!

Comment: Just a comment about this... just because requests come from the same IP doesn't mean they're the same user. I worked for a university where users in the dorms were behind carrier-grade NAT, with about 2,000 users to an external IP address (this was a big problem when one kid decided to attack PayPal...).